# Kotlin clickable button in ListView

Tags: android, kotlin, button, android-listview

I am making a Kotlin recipe app and I have a list of dishes name with a button to view the dish that will be generated whenever a new dish is added in a list view. The button is supposed to navigate users to a new activity where the recipe of the dish will be shown. However, the button does not work. I have tried a few suggested solutions but still does not work.

xml file of the list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    tools:context=".ViewRecipe">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/recipeList"
        android:layout_width="367dp"
        android:layout_height="565dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="Recipe List"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

xml for button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Recipes">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/recipeView2"
        android:layout_width="228dp"
        android:layout_height="28dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="23dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/recipeDetails"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:text="View"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Kotlin file for the list view:

```
package com.example.recipeapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ListView
import com.google.firebase.database.*

class ViewRecipe : AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var ref: DatabaseReference
    lateinit var recipeList: MutableList<AddRecipeModelClass>
    lateinit var listView: ListView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_recipe)

        recipeList = mutableListOf()
        ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("addRecipes")
        listView = findViewById(R.id.recipeList)

        ref.addValueEventListener(object: ValueEventListener {
            override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) {
                TODO("Not yet implemented")
            }

            override fun onDataChange(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    recipeList.clear()
                    for(h in snapshot.children){
                        val recipe = h.getValue(AddRecipeModelClass::class.java)
                        recipeList.add(recipe!!)
                    }

                    val adapter = RecipeAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.activity_recipes, recipeList)
                    listView.adapter = adapter
                }
            }

        });
    }
}
```

Kotlin file for the button:

```
package com.example.recipeapp

import android.content.Intent
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Button

class Recipes : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_recipes)

        val navView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.recipeDetails)
        navView.setOnClickListener{
            val intent = Intent(this, RecipeDetails::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
        }
    }
}
```

RecipeAdapter.kt

```
package com.example.recipeapp

import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.TextView

class RecipeAdapter(val mCtx: Context, val layoutResId: Int, val recipeList: List<AddRecipeModelClass>)

    : ArrayAdapter<AddRecipeModelClass>(mCtx, layoutResId, recipeList) {

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
        val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
        val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, null)

        val recipeView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recipeView2)

        val recipe = recipeList[position]

        recipeView.text = recipe.dishName

        return view
    }
}
```

Edit:

I have found that the issue is occurring because the "view" button is inside a list view. I tried using a "button" placed outside the listview and it works just fine. I am unable to solve it using the solutions found on the internet.

The image shows the 2 types of buttons. View is inside a listview, button is outside listview.
[image: Image for better understanding]

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post error logs?

Comment: I do not see any errors being shown, just nothing happens when I click the button

Comment: can you post a code for the adapter class

Comment: @Sharvin does my answer solve your problem? Are you still facing the same problem?

Comment: @LakhwinderSingh I have added it.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't read your entire code but one problem that I found is this:

```
navView.setOnClickListener{
       val intent = Intent(this, RecipeDetails::class.java)
       //                  ^^^^
       startActivity(intent)
}
```

The `this` in that scope refers to the `View.OnClickListener` object passed to `setOnclickListener` function. Not to the application context.

From [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/this-expressions.html) :

> To access this from an outer scope (a class, or extension function, or
> labeled function literal with receiver) we write this@label where
> @label is a label on the scope this is meant to be from

So you should be doing this instead:

```
navView.setOnClickListener{
       val intent = Intent(this@Recipes, RecipeDetails::class.java)
       //                    ^^^^ note the label @Recipes
       startActivity(intent)
}
```

---

Alternatively you can call `Intent` constructor from outside the object of `View.OnClickListener`, in the `onCreate` function:

```
val intent = Intent(this, RecipeDetails::class.java)
val navView = findViewById<Button>(R.id.recipeDetails)

navView.setOnClickListener{
       startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: I tried both the suggested methods and still face the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your activity class and make sure you AddRecipeModelClass is parcelable

```
private val onItemAction: (AddRecipeModelClass) -> Unit = { it ->
val intent = Intent(this@ViewRecipe , RecipeDetails::class.java)
intent.putExtra("recipe", it)
startActivity(intent)
}
```

get a recipe from intent in a new activity

Add a click listener to your adapters getView

```
class RecipeAdapter(val mCtx: Context, val layoutResId: Int,
       val recipeList: List<AddRecipeModelClass>,private val onItemSelected: (AddRecipeModelClass) -> Unit?)
        : ArrayAdapter<AddRecipeModelClass>(mCtx, layoutResId, recipeList) {  
        override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup): View {
            val layoutInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mCtx)
            val view: View = layoutInflater.inflate(layoutResId, null)   
            val recipeView = view.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.recipeView2)
            val btn= findViewById<Button>(R.id.recipeDetails)                 
            val recipe = recipeList[position]
            btn.setOnClickListener{
                onItemSelected(recipe)
            } 
            recipeView.text = recipe.dishName    
            return view
        }
    }
```

add function to the constructor

```
 val adapter = RecipeAdapter(applicationContext, R.layout.activity_recipes, recipeList,onItemAction)
```